# Can I safely ignore these pthread warnings via glibc?

Tags: gcc, pthreads, compiler-warnings, glibc

I am getting a pair of warnings with version 2.22 of glibc:

```
In file included from /net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include/pthread.h:23:0,
                 from foo.h:48,
                 from foo.c:23:
/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include/sched.h:74:57: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list
 extern int sched_rr_get_interval (__pid_t __pid, struct timespec *__t) __THROW;
                                                         ^
/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include/sched.h:74:57: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
In file included from foo.h:48:0,
                 from foo.c:23:
/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include/pthread.h:1002:21: warning: ‘struct timespec’ declared inside parameter list
        const struct timespec *__restrict __abstime)
                     ^
```

And:

```
In file included from /net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include/sys/param.h:26:0,
                 from foo.h:51,
                 from foo.c:23:
/net/module/sw/glibc/2.22/include/limits.h:123:3: warning: #include_next is a GCC extension
 # include_next <limits.h>
   ^
```

I am using GCC 5.3.0 with this version of glibc.

Since these warnings are referencing an external library I do not control, can I safely ignore these warnings if my application otherwise appears to pass tests?

My concern is that these warnings (particularly those related to `pthread`) may indicate the introduction of subtle bugs that I do not have tests to catch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these warnings should be harmless, but the `struct timespec` warning is certainly odd.  Usually, they would be masked by GCC's warning suppression for system headers.